# Typedef usage from one header file in second header file

Tags: c, project, typedef

Basically, I need to have typedef in one header file and use it on another header.

`myType.h`:

```
#ifndef deque_H
#define deque_H
#include "deque.h"

typedef int intDef;

#endif
```

`deque.h`:

```
#ifndef deque_H
#define deque_H
#include "myType.h"
typedef struct dequeNode *link;
struct dequeNode{
    intDef data;
    link next;
    //count
};
#endif
```

I want to use `intDef` in `deque.h`, but I get project error `\deque.h|6|error: unknown type name 'intDef'|`

Does anybody have a clue what's wrong? `myType.h` is in the same project.

Comment: Why are you including `deque.h` in `myType.h` ? Plus, your defguards in 1st are confusing

Comment: I'm trying to find why I get the error, so I'm including unnecessary stuff, hoping it will work. I'm kinda green in C.

Comment: Including files where they are not necessary is also a source of errors. And you definitely need to change the defguards, as once you define a symbol `deque_H` in one file, and then check in another whether it's defined or not, you will never execute your `typedef int intDef`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You prevent your `myType.h` from ever being executed, since you use the same flag as in the other file. You need to choose any other symbol and check if it's defined:

```
#ifndef myType_H
#define myType_H

typedef int intDef;

#endif
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked wonders. And, as I see, if header file doesn't have any defguards, it works too. Is it better to have def's or not?

Comment: another problem is circular includes

Comment: It is better, especially in large projects, when you just can't keep track of what is included when. But for every file - a different symbol. If you don't have them, you risk defining the same macro or function more than once, which will result in redefinition errors in your `.obj` files, at the linker level.